# How do I craft a REST API call to search on a Docker Tag, without knowing the repo

Tags: rest, artifactory

Here is jfrog's REST API documentation: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

In the UI, you're able to simply select the Package Type 'Docker' and provide a 'tag' to search on. And it immediately brings up the correct Artifact. I'm looking for the correct API call [ie: /api/serach/artifact?] to use to search on a Docker Tag.